# FlashDevelop 4.0.1 Error while trying to format code

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I´m trying to format my class in FlashDevelop.

This class has 1132 lines of code.

The problem is... FlashDevelop isn´t formatting the code.

If I try to format small amount of AS3 code, the program works fine.

It seems that, Flash Develop has a bug trying to format big amount of code.

There´s any workaround for that?

Any fix for the bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy functions individually into another file and format there and then paste them back in. Though 1132 lines isn't that much, if it is not working I would just format it myself.

Comment: yeah. its a bit - but not overly large.